# How to handle events from kafka lister using POJO's?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to use the annotation @KafkaListener and listen to my own event:

```
  public class Listener {
        @KafkaListener(id = "SimpleListener", topics = "mytopic")
        public void receive(SimpleEvent event) {
             ...
        }
    }

  @Component     
  public class MyEventHandler {
      @EventListener
      public void eventHandler(SimpleEvent event) {
           ...
      }
   }
```

Is this possible to do this way? i want to listen to event and handle in a service component for each different event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. That is possible via `MessageConverter` injection into the `ContainerFactory`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes

Comment: There is an `Introduction` chapter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_introduction.html#_introduction. What you need is to add a `MessageConverter` into the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean definition to be able to deserialize `byte[]` into your `SimpleEvent`.

Comment: I just want to listen to the event when it is consumed but nothing happens when the messages arrives.. it's really necessary?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your ` @EventListener` isn't related to the `@KafkaListener`. The first one is triggered by the `ApplicationEventPublisher` and the second one by the Apache Kafka consumer. So, if you want to trigger an application event you should use the first one from your `receive()` method.

Comment: In the Event Consumption there's an example showing an event handler : public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) and it's annotated with @EventListener i thought that's possible to trigger an event when the message's is listened by `@KafkaListener` and then handle in another class (MyEventHandler)

Comment: No, that's not. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events-annotation. The `@KafkaListener` is triggered by the container. I'm not sure why do you need `@EventListener` there since you have just consumed data from the Kafka.

Comment: My idea is trigger an event and have different classes to handle a message and send an e-mail or publish another event.. i saw something like this on CDI events..

Comment: Right, you can do that via `ApplicationEventPublisher` from the ` @KafkaListener`. See `ApplicationEventPublisherAware`